# Format Date, sort as calendar and use as SSRS parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have a DateTime field that I want to summarise and format to YYYY mmm, then use as an SSRS parameter to filter my query.

Q1. When I use the format option the dates I get back are sorted as text e.g.

1. 2022 Apr
2. 2022 Feb
3. 2022 Jan
4. 2022 Mar

Q2. How do I sort as per the calendar e.g.

1. 2022 Jan
2. 2022 Feb
3. 2022 Mar
4. 2022 Apr

Q3. How do I use the values of this parameter in my WHERE clause to filter my dates? So if someone chooses "2022 Mar" I only get data where the DateTime field contains March 2022.

Comment: *"How do I sort as per the calendar"* Assuming that you are passing a date and time value back from your data set, just sort by the date column. If you aren't passing a date and time value back from data set, then *do* pass a date and time value; stop using string data types for dates.

Comment: When you have users from many countries who do not understand database date formats and as this will be part of an SSRS report filter they will be using. Sometimes you have no choice but to convert dates into strings

Comment: In the presentation layer you can *format* them, sure. But don't change the data type in the SQL layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try_convert(date,...)` will assume the 1st of the month if no day is given

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2022 Apr')
,('2022 Feb')
,('2022 Jan')
,('2022 Mar')
 
Select *
  From @YourTable
  Order By try_convert(Date,SomeCol)
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol
2022 Jan
2022 Feb
2022 Mar
2022 Apr
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. try_convert is not something I have come across before

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it out by just using 'ORDER BY'

EX:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_DATES
(Month_Year Date)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_DATES
SELECT 
        '2022 APR',
        '2022 FEB',
        '2022 JAN'
        
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_DATES
ORDER BY Month_Year
```